# Windows 10 doesn't boot after cloning it from HDD to SSD

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, ssd

I have tried to clone Windows 10 from a HDD to a SSD using Macrium Reflect. When I try to
boot Windows 10 it first asks what language the keyboard should be. I then asks whether to
boot from CD/DVD or a Hard Drive. Regardless of which option I choose the computer just restarts and nothing changed. I still have Windows 10 installed on the old HDD. I have tried to remove the SSD but it won't boot from the old HDD either. I have also tried changing the boot order.

Comment: Not the first time I see here such a problem with Macrium Reflect. Try cloning with [AOMEI Backupper](https://www.ubackup.com/help/disk-clone.html).

Comment: What is the model of the SSD? Is it NVMe? Are you using Legacy BIOS or UEFI boot?

Comment: It is a Intel 665p with NVMe and I use UEFI boot.